# Adding comma between quotes (format) in printf changes the output?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, scanf, line-endings

I am facing a very weird issue that i can only produce on linux. I really couldnt find anything like it on the internet, but if my searching skills are not good enough, I apologize if this was a repeat of any question.

Take the following minimal viable code below: I cut back much as i could while still having the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10
#define MAXNAME 30

typedef struct sup{
    int rating;
    char supName[MAXNAME];
}sup;

typedef struct spec{
    char name[MAXNAME];
    float width;
    float height;
    float depth;
    char material[MAXNAME];
    sup supvisor[MAX];
}spec;

int read_Supervisors(char fileName[], spec *specread){
    int i=0;

    char buffer[MAX];
    FILE *supervisors = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while (i < MAX && fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), supervisors)) {

        if(sscanf(buffer, "%19s %d", specread->supvisor[i].supName, &specread->supvisor[i].rating) == 2){
            i++;}}

    fclose(supervisors);

    return i;
}

void read_Specs(char fileName[],spec *spec1){
    FILE *specs = fopen(fileName, "r");

    fscanf(specs, "%29[^\n]\n %19s\n %f\n %f\n %f", spec1->name, spec1->material,&spec1->width, &spec1->height, &spec1->depth);
    fclose(specs);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    spec spec1 = {.name = ""}; // Initialize .name at zero
    //Read specs file.
    read_Specs(argv[1],&spec1);

    int iteration = read_Supervisors(argv[2], &spec1), 
    selectedSuper = 1, 
    calculatedDays = 50;

    float priceOfProject = 1;

    //Print all the values.
    printf("Dear %s,"
           "\nThank you for your order.\n"
           "Your retaining wall of specifications:\n"
           "Material: %s\n"
           "width: %.2f m\n"
           "height: %.2f m\n"
           "depth: %.3f m\n"
           "Will be completed in %d days and the assigned project supervisor is %s\n"
           "The estimated price is: $%.2f\n", spec1.name, spec1.material, spec1.width,spec1.height,spec1.depth,calculatedDays, spec1.supvisor[selectedSuper].supName,priceOfProject);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
,ear Jason Oliver
Thank you for your order.
Your retaining wall of specifications:
Material: Concrete
width: 5.50 m
height: 1.00 m
depth: 0.250 m
Will be completed in 50 days and the assigned project supervisor is Sally
The estimated price is: $1.00
```

Notice that the print out was ,ear rather than Dear Jason oliver,
when removing the comma `Dear %s,` to `Dear %s` it works perfectly. I can have the comma before the `%s` but not after.

I have tried a many things, increasing the #defines, I have tried splitting to multiple printf, i have tried a different versions of C11, C23, I have also tried updating my linux. I gonna note that this is a clean install of linux.

Here is some information about the linux(22.04) env I am using:
Linux Linux 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Compiler version:
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0

structure of the files:

specs.dat file:

```
Jason Oliver
Concrete
5.50
1.0
0.250
```

Builders.dat file:

```
Bob 50
Sally 78
Jian 69
Hecctor 89
```

Comment: `#define MAX 10` is too small to handle the longest line in Builders.dat

Comment: @RetiredNinja, The file only has 4 supervisors, i also have a check to make sure I do not go over the 10 lines when reading the file.

Comment: `char buffer[MAX];` then `fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), supervisors)` where `Hecctor 89` is more than 10 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your input file must be using `\r\n` line endings prevalent on Windows, rather than the single `\n` that Unix is using. Your code reads the name up to the `\n` character, so `\r` becomes part of the `name`. When you print the name to the terminal, `\r` instructs it to move the cursor to the beginning of the line (it's a **carriage return** control character). The next character you print after that is a comma, thus it overwrites the 'D' of the 'Dear' that's located at the same position.

You can fix your `fscanf` to exclude `\r` from the string too. Note that the following `\n` in the format string is incorrect in such a situation. A simple space will do the trick to skip both `\r` and `\n`, as well as other white-space characters:

```
fscanf(specs, "%29[^\r\n] %19s %f %f %f", spec1->name, spec1->material,&spec1->width, &spec1->height, &spec1->depth);
```

Alternatively, if it's an option, you can fix your input files using the `dos2unix` command that's available for most operating systems:

```
$ dos2unix specs.dat
```

Comment: Good catch. It's a shame that we are still plagued by this stupid `'\n'` vs. `'\r\n'` issue.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Actually a shortcoming in the library implementation / configuration. The file has been `fopen()`ed in text mode ("r", not "rb"), so the library *could* be converting line endings on the fly. Of course, it's easier to not bother with this, assume text mode and binary mode are identical, and point to everyone who's not using a lone `\n` for line ends...

Comment: @DevSolar AFAIK converting `\r\n` to `\n` is not POSIX compliant, so even if you're in the 'lets convert camp', that's more of standard shortcoming than a library implementation. IMO though POSIX did the right thing of removing the distinction between text and binary modes. Having the library do any sort of conversions introduces the complication that `fread` can read a different number of `chars` than reported by the file size (through `ftell` or other means), and that causes all sorts of bugs if programmers aren't aware of it.

Comment: @DevSolar "library could be converting line endings on the fly" --> The _should_ applies to native line-endings.  Text files with alternative encodings ([BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation), [Ctrl-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file#EOF_character)) are always a problem.

Comment: I have a question, what happens if the file was created without the \r or \r\n ending?

Does ``[^\r\n]`` only skip it if it cant find \r\n endings or will it cause issues? I am really sorry if such question is stupid/"Noob" question.

Comment: @DanielBoos `%[^\r\n]` stops that specifier if either a single `'\r'` or `'\n'` is read.  It is _unread_ for the next part of the scan format.

Comment: @YakovGalka Converting \r\n to \n is C standard compliant. And it doesn't much matter what POSIX "removed" or not as long as other line endings are still around -- AFAIR Microsoft doesn't feel much love for POSIX. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar An implementation need not distinguish between text streams and binary streams. In POSIX, all streams are binary streams so its standard I/O library calls cannot convert line endings.

Comment: @IanAbbott It need not, but it conceivably and conveniently *could*, making it a shortcoming *not* doing so, which is all I said. I don't quite get why people keep confusing the C language standard and POSIX.

Comment: @DevSolar Are you suggesting that the POSIX standard could be amended? If so, which input text stream character sequences should be converted to newline? And what should newline be converted to in output text streams? Of course such a change is impossible for backwards compatibility with the existing codebase.

Comment: @IanAbbott What gave you the impression that I would care in any way or form about POSIX? Past, present, or future? It's the Unix counterpart to Microsoft's APIs, a non-portable, platform-specific add-on to the language that thinks too highly of itself.

Comment: @DevSolar You said that it's a "a shortcoming in the library implementation". "The library" here is **glibc**, which doesn't do the conversion by design, due to POSIX compliance. So it follows that you're either saying that it's POSIX's shortcoming, or that glibc shouldn't have stayed compliant with POSIX because you don't care about POSIX. While we could constructively discuss the former, the later is just utter religious nonsense. In reality nobody outside Windows devs cares about Windows' past, present, or future. Personally I use binary i/o on Windows too, and write out files with LF.

Comment: @YakovGalka Only that Windows is not the only platform that does NOT use a single `\n` for line endings. Not taking into account other platforms **is** a shortcoming of **any** library, and the POSIX camp is just as religiously nonsensical about claiming **they** got it right as Windows is. This is pointless. The library *could* translate line endings in text mode, but doesn't. That is a shortcoming. Period.

Comment: @DevSolar Even if you don't care about POSIX, I hope you care about backwards compatibility.

Comment: @DevSolar Actually Windows is the only modern OS left that still uses those. And even on Windows many tools understand LF without problem.

Comment: @YakovGalka So it's somehow ok that glibc doesn't? I disagree. Can we stop spamming this thread now?